# How can I add a second row on the left, on a dropdown menu? (still looking for answer ... :c )

Tags: html, css

i was wondering how can I make a second row on my dopdown menu, that is aligned to its respective line, on the left side.

I made this as a test, because i have links that can't be leaked out, as this is from a private organization that I'm an recent Intern. I do't have currently all the learning i need to make ths, but I tried several things that i searched, and none seem to be working, Im doin' something wrong

Here is my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  font-family: Sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

#header {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #24A1FF;
}

#nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 230px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #5AB8FF;
}

#logo {
  padding: 10px;
}

main {
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  /* Set this to the height of the header */
  left: 230px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background: #fff;
}

.innertube {
  margin: 15px;
  /* Provides padding for the content */
}

p {
  color: #555;
}

nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a {
  font-size: 220%;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*IE6 fix*/

* html body {
  padding: 100px 0 0 230px;
}

* html main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

ww.under {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #1aa3ff;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: black;
  margin: 0px -1px 0px -1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  <!-- display: inline;
  -->
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: right;
  background-color: #99d6ff;
  min-width: 60px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ffffff
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #1aa3ff;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<header id="header">
  <div id="logo">
    <center>
      <h1>Pesquisa de documentos - ATENDIMENTO</h1>
    </center>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="innertube">

    <center>
      <h1>Processos</h1>
    </center>
    <div class="container">


      <ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Secretaria </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Receção de Pedidos de Registo de Cidadãos Comunitários</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de Pedidos de Exame,Concessão, Renovação e 2ª Via Carta Caçador</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de Pedidos de Inumaçãos,Exumação e Transladação no Cemitério</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de Receitas Provenientes dos Postos de Cobrança de Outros Serviços</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entrega de Licenças e Procedimentos Sujeitos a Taxa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de Rendas de Ocupação de Espaços Municipais e Habitação Social</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Águas </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Receção de leituras de consumo de água</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Emissão de guias de recebimento dos pedidos de ligação de água e saneamento</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de pedidos de reparação de avarias</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Cobrança de consumos de água</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Celebração de contratos água e residuos solidos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Emissão de guias de recebimento de execuções fiscais</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de pedidos de informação e actualização</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção de pedidos de limpeza de fossa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção e instrução de cessação de contratos de fornecimento de água</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção e instrução de pedidos de ligação de água e saneamento</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rectificação de leituras</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Edificação e Urbanismo </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Receção pedidos verbais</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção documentos sem emissao de guia</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Entrega Licencas Certidoes Pag com taxa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Receção Certidoes Inf Vistorias Processo com taxa</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ficha tecnica de habitacao Averb Alvara</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Licenciamento obras loteamentos utilizacao proj. especialidades</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Educação </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Receção de candidaturas, de inscrições e pedidos de licença no ambito da sociocultural</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Declaração e justificação de faltas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Procedimentos da Educação sujeitos a pagamento de taxas</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Balcão do Munícipe </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Receção e Encaminhamento</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Atendimento Telefonico</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Levantamento e entrega de documentos sem taxa</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos Recursos Humanos </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Necessidades de Competências</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <button class="dropbtn">Processos de Sistema de Informação </button>
          <div class="dropdown-content">
            <li><a href="#">Circulação Interna de Documentos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Operacionalizar o Sistema de Informação</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Registo Encaminhamento de Correspondencia</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<nav id="nav">
  <div class="innertube">
    <h1>MENU</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="Atendimento.html"><button class="dropbtn">Atendimento </button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dropdown">
        <a href="Educacao.html"><button class="dropbtn">Educação </button></a>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2x312xjc/)

If the idea is create another line on your menu, inside the `<nav id="nav">` just add another `<div class="innertube">`

Comment: No, i actually wanted it to be applied on the left side of the middle dropdown menus, you know? Not on the actual menu on the left, my objective is add a code tag on the left side of the middle section, to tell like, the first option is code 323252 (random numers), the second option would have, lets say code 2365732, and so on, matching the numbers of options available, same size, you understand? The left menu is fine like i have :P and thanks alot for having some time to answer me :)

Comment: Hi, I didn't understand your idea pretty much yet... let me know if this is what you are looking for [Demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/0xt866e0/)

Comment: So you see the menu, where it says Processos Secretaria, Processos água, etc etc.. i want to make a similar thing but behind each one of those buttons, instead of that one row of buttons, add a second row behind those, aligned, tell me if u didn't get it yet, i can try to make a draw on paint or something to make an example, thats for sticking with me trying to help..

Comment: yep... should be great if I have a wire frame with your intentions on it

Comment: Should be somethink like this: https://gyazo.com/b1f4cd440b906d17dd1d334a5e432841

Comment: Yes! That is it! kinda, but i can work my way around what i really want it to be, really thanks for not giving up on me :P It's my first post here, how do I +1 or something? thanks alot <3

Comment: You are welcome! ;) just click on the arrow up above the number on the left of the answer